# Is it possible to track internet disconnection in a user's active session?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

We have a Rails website where users takeup online quizzes. 20-30% times users will report that due to internet disconnection they were unable to complete the quiz. Is there any way to track how many times internet disconnection occured when a user was on a particular page.

Comment: you can also send a request to his ip by `Net::HTTP` and capture the error `Net::HTTPRequestTimeOut` or 408

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on how and why you want to track it. You are able to do this with the window.navigator.onLine property on the client side which you could attempt to log to analytics when the user is online again to get an idea of how frequently this happens - [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NavigatorOnLine/onLine).

If you wanted to know on the server side, depending on the resources available to you, you may want to create a websocket ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/WebSockets)) to the client. The websocket will be an ongoing connection between your rails app and the clients browser and any disconnections should be noticeable on the server side which you can keep track of. There are existing libraries for doing websockets with rails but remember that this option will likely take up more server resources as it requires persistent connections with all the online users of your site but you could transmit all your application data over this channel saving the other connections that may otherwise be required.

Another option which would require less resources but possibly more work on your part would be to have a script on the client that polls the server in some way to let it know it's still online and you could link that 'keep-alive' request to the user's information and determine a reasonable time-out if one doesn't arrive which may require a scheduled task on the server.

Comment: So will it be a good idea to fire requests at regular intervals and save the count of failed requests?

Comment: You can certainly do that and it shouldn't be too noisy if you set an appropriate timeout. I've seen that done before without too many issues, the biggest problem with this option (and the first one) is how you get that data back to the server. If your users have connectivity issues and they subsequently leave the page then you won't have any mechanism to get the value of that counter on to the server to know that it happened. So if you do go with this approach you might consider putting that information into localStorage or something to be sent should the user return.